# how to change a word in a specific group using sed?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I need to change a word in a specific `define service` section where `service_description` is `NRPE - NTP_TIME` and where `contact_groups` is `opsgenie-sla1`, I need to change to `opsgenie-sla2` and I would like to do it with `sed` command to shorten my work because I need to do it on multiple hosts.
Below is a snippet of the file; for example

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service

        service_description             NRPE
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    24x7
        max_check_attempts              3
        check_interval           5
        retry_interval            2
        contact_groups                  opsgenie-sla1

        notification_period             24x7
        check_command                   check_nrpe_port_ssl
        }

    define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       dns1
        service_description             NRPE - NTP_TIME
        servicegroups                   ntp_checks
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    24x7
        max_check_attempts              3
        check_interval           5
        retry_interval            2
        contact_groups                  opsgenie-sla1


        check_command                   check_custom_nrpe!check_ntp_time
        }
```

Comment: Does it have to be sed or do you just want any tool that will let you automate it?

Comment: The document looks like it's written in some structured document format. What reads this (Nagios?) and is the format _called_ something? I'm fishing for whether there's a dedicated processor of these types of files that would let you work with them in a safe and efficient manner.

Comment: sed command is required, but if you want you can show me this automation tool :)

Comment: `sed` is from the 70s with an API from that era. Would switching to perl from the 80s be an option?

Comment: yes, perl can be used

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: See e.g. http://pynag.org

Comment: If perl can be used, why say sed is required and why couldn't awk be used?

Comment: Does the string `define service{` always start at the beginning of the line? And immediately following a blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`, assuming there's no other `{`s, `}`s inside those `{...}` services, you could do something like:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e '
  s{^\h*define\h+service\s*\{.*?\}}{
    my $service = $&;
    if ($service =~ m{^\h*service_description\h+NRPE - NTP_TIME\h*$}m) {
      $service =~ s{^\h*contact_groups\h+opsgenie-sla\K1\h*$}{2}gm;
    }
    $service;
  }mges' -- your-file
```

`perl -p` is `perl`'s `sed` mode. With `-0777`, we define the record separator as something impossible, so the one and only record is the full file.

Then we apply a substitution using a common technique: in the pattern, match the whole `define service {...}`, and the replacement is interpreted as code (thanks to the `e` flag), which is the match with the contact group substituted only if the match had the right `service_description`.

The substitution of the `contact_groups` is with:

```
s{^\h*contact_groups\h+opsgenie-sla\K1\h*$}{2}gm
```

Which here, replaces the `1<horizontal-spacing-if-any>` with `2`.

Change to:

```
s{^\h*contact_groups\h+\K.*}{opsgenie-sla2}gm
```

For instance to change the `contact_groups` to `opsgenie-sla2` regardless of what they were before.

Or:

```
s{^\h*contact_groups\h+(.*,\h*)?opsgenie-sla\K1(?=\h*,|\h*$)}{2}gm
```

To change that `1` to `2` in `opsgenie-sla1` that is possibly preceded or followed by more comma-separated words.

Or:

```
s{^\h*contact_groups\h+(.*,\h*)?\Kopsgenie-sla1(?=\h*,|\h*$)}{opsgenie-sla2}gm
```

To replace the whole word. `\K` marks what's `K`ept in the match (`$&`), `(?=...)` is a look-ahead operator, what it finds is not included in the match.

You can learn about those `s{regexp}{replacement}flags` `m{regexp}flags` operators with `perldoc -f s`, `perldoc -f m` and about the regexp syntax with `perldoc perlre`. `perldoc perlsyn` about the syntax `perldoc perlrun` about invocation and options, or start the whole journey with `perldoc perl`.

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot

Comment: what to do if there is more than one item in contact_group?

Comment: @Linuxuser, see edit. If that's not sufficient, please edit your question to specify the extra requirements.

Comment: let's assume that in contact_groups there is xyz,xyz,opsgenie-sla1,xyz the goal is to create xyz,xyz,opsgenie-sla2,xyz but how to do it replacing the whole word than one letter?  @Stéphane

Comment: @Linuxuser, see edit.

Comment: now it works perfectly, thank you. @Stéphane Chazelas

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using GNU `sed`, but you will lose the correct indentation of the file, better to use the solution provided by Stéphane:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' <filename> | sed 's/\(define service{.*service_description\s*NRPE - NTP_TIME.*contact_groups\s.*\)opsgenie-sla1/\1opsgenie-sla2/g'
```

Comment: An explanation of what these parameters do and how it works would be quite helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/define service.*\{/ { prt(); numLines=0 }
{
    lines[++numLines] = $0
    tag = $1
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    tag2lineNr[tag] = numLines
    tag2val[tag] = $0
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   lineNr) {
    if ( tag2val["service_description"] == "NRPE - NTP_TIME" ) {
        lineNr = tag2lineNr["contact_groups"]
        sub(/opsgenie-sla1/,"opsgenie-sla2",lines[lineNr])
    }
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        print lines[lineNr]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
define service{
        use                             generic-service

        service_description             NRPE
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    24x7
        max_check_attempts              3
        check_interval           5
        retry_interval            2
        contact_groups                  opsgenie-sla1

        notification_period             24x7
        check_command                   check_nrpe_port_ssl
        }

    define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       dns1
        service_description             NRPE - NTP_TIME
        servicegroups                   ntp_checks
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    24x7
        max_check_attempts              3
        check_interval           5
        retry_interval            2
        contact_groups                  opsgenie-sla2


        check_command                   check_custom_nrpe!check_ntp_time
        }
```